# UICollectionView stops loading cells after moveItemAtIndexPath:toIndexPath:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, uicollectionview

I have a `UICollectionView` with `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which contains many items. I want to reorder a cell due to the user input.

```
[self.collectionView moveItemAtIndexPath:indexPath toIndexPath:newIndexPath];
```

After execution of this code, **the collection view doesn't update it's contents when scrolling**. It doesn't show next cells. It doesn't even call `cellForItemAtIndexPath:` but it's content size is correct (the layout "updates" it's state).
Therefore we can only see the cells which were distributed on the collection view before the reorder.
Any clues what might be the issue ? Are there any known workarounds for this issue? The app is iOS 8 only and the collection view is used with the UICollectionViewFlowLayout.

EDIT: When I call `[self.collectionView reloadData];` the datasource is not even asked for anything, too.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with the `UICollectionViewCell`. High level description is that the cell is sent a method `actionForKey` from my code during the move animation. It caused the cell to stay in internal `being animated` state. I couldn't find reasonable workaround and refactored some bits in order to avoid `actionForKey` call. Now everything works as expected.

Comment: Please, could you explain closer, where did you find the 'being animated' state? I have a similar problem of not loading new cells (in completely different, but very complicated situation) and I want to find what caused it...

Comment: @MatejVargovčík To be honest with you, I don't remember. I think it meant that I called `actionForKey` from my code, and it caused the cell to "think" it is being animated. You can find more information about actionForKey here: https://www.objc.io/issues/12-animations/animating-custom-layer-properties/